# KeystoneJS relationships many to many with nested

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query, keystonejs

Trying to figure out if its possible to have a many to many relationship but nested.

Right now I have users that belong to groups which I can resolve without a problem through relationships.

So user A belongs to Group X, Y and Z. This works properly.
My issue is management of these groups is a nightmare as a user can belong to many groups.

What I want to do is associate a user with a company and then nest that within another group. That way my new group will include multiple companies which will in turn include the users.

Does anyone know if this is currently possible in KeystoneJS/Mongoose?

I setup a new model for my new group and setup a relationship but so far am not getting the users that belong to that group.

To clarify what I mean see below:

Sam belongs to XYZ Company
Jason belongs to XYZ Company

XYZ Company belongs to the "Internet Outage" group.

I am able to reference the Internet Outage Group and in turn show that XYZ Company belongs in it, but I am not able to show that Sam and Jason belong to XYZ Company.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it could help you: https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate

Comment: Can [Relationship Filters](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#relationship-fields "Relationship Filters") help you?